# How to remove node below Post.all @ static page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app when I am rendering Post.all in my static page home I am getting some code like this at the end of the page

```html
[#<Post id: 3, title: "I loved you...", content: "how to short and place enter if the line is large ...", created_at: "2015-04-03 09:17:48", updated_at: "2015-04-03 10:34:47", image_file_name: "Penguins.jpg", image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 777835, image_updated_at: "2015-04-03 09:18:50">, #<Post id: 2, title: "I loved you...", content: "I loved you, and I probably still do,\r\nAnd for a w...", created_at: "2015-04-02 15:44:19", updated_at: "2015-04-02 15:44:19", image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil>, #<Post id: 1, title: "উত্তম ও অধম", content: "কুকুর আসিয়া এমন কামড়\r\nদিল পথিকের পায়\r\nকামড়ের চ...", created_at: "2015-04-02 15:41:51", updated_at: "2015-04-02 15:41:51", image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil>]
```

how to remove that or stop getting that?

here is my gemfile

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'



gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2.1'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc




group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  
  gem 'byebug'

 
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

In Pages controller home action I have put @post = Post.all

and in view I have put

```html
<%= @post.each do |post|%>
<% if post.image.present?%>

<h1> <%= link_to post.title, post %></h1><br>

<%= image_tag post.image.url(:thumb)%>

<%= simple_format post.content %>
<hr color="blue" >
<% else %>

<h1> <%= link_to post.title, post %></h1><br>
<%= simple_format post.content %>
<hr color="blue">

<% end %>

<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should remove the `=` in the first loop `<%= @post.each do |post|%>`

```
<% @post.each do |post|%>
  <% if post.image.present?%>

    <h1> <%= link_to post.title, post %></h1><br>

    <%= image_tag post.image.url(:thumb)%>

    <%= simple_format post.content %>
    <hr color="blue" >
  <% else %>

    <h1> <%= link_to post.title, post %></h1><br>
    <%= simple_format post.content %>
    <hr color="blue">

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: To expand.  %= will display what is evaluated.  Just % will only evaluate

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am very new in rails basic syntax mistakes also happen . Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Don't worry every future expert will have to be start as a beginner :). Don't forget to vote the answer. btw Austio add a good point that you should know about `=`